# android keytool.exe problem

Tags: android

I am trying to extract MD5 fingerprint on Mac OS x and facing with 2 problems:

1) Where is my debug.keystore I cannot find .android file anywhere in the system, it is supposed to be at /Users/tugce/.android/debug.keystore

2) When I run the Keytool.exe program I get this error

```
-bash: /Users/tugce/Desktop/android/setup/jdk1.7.0/bin/keytool: cannot execute binary file
logout
```

EDİT: I guess there is no need to run Keytool.exe in mac os x platform, go directly terminal and write keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore this gives you MD5 fingerprint

Any solutions?

Comment: Here is the fine doc:
http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect17_d1e6459.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:

Check in your terminal if the debug.keystore is in the right folder using the following in a terminal:

```
cd .android/
ls
```

After that just type `cd` to go to your root folder.

Step 2:

On your root directory run the following in a terminal:

```
$ keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android
```

This will not work some times. In that case try:

```
keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Step 3:

After the terminal request you to enter password ("Enter keystore password:") just type your password.

Note! the default password is empty (just hit Enter/return key)